# Can a sorcerer use a scroll of a spell not known?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I'm a bit confused because the section on [Magic Items](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items) that talks about scrolls being [Spell Completion](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items#TOC-Using-Items) items states;

> If he can't already cast the spell, there's a chance he'll make a mistake.

Then the [Scrolls](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/scrolls) section states 3 conditions to use scrolls;

> To have any chance of activating a scroll spell, the scroll user must
>   meet the following requirements.
>
> - The spell must be of the correct type (arcane or divine). Arcane spellcasters (wizards, sorcerers, and bards) can only use scrolls
>     containing arcane spells, and divine spellcasters (clerics, druids,
>     paladins, and rangers) can only use scrolls containing divine spells.
>     (The type of scroll a character creates is also determined by his
>     class.)
> - The user must have the spell on her *class list*.
> - The user must have the requisite ability score.

Emphasis mine.  So does that mean that a sorcerer can use any scroll as long as the scroll's spell comes from the wizard/sorcerer spell list, or will there be a problem when using a scroll of a spell he does not know.

I would assume the same also applies to a bard?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Sorcerers can use a scroll of a Sorcerer/Wizard spell they do not know.

The "If he can't already cast the spell" line that causes you confusion is more clear in context:

> To use a spell completion item safely, a character must be of high enough level in the right class to cast the spell already. If he can't already cast the spell, there's a chance he'll make a mistake.

It refers to the Sorcerer's class level, the character's potential to learn and cast such a spell.

The clause you emphasized in the second quote, "The user must have the spell on her *class list*", reinforces this. It mentions that the spell must be on the correct list (in this case, the Sor/Wiz) list. It need not be on that Sorcerer's list of spells known - that would be a more stringent condition. Luckily for Sorcerers, that's not the case.

And yes, the same applies to Bards.

Comment: Since you mention bards, I just wanted to note that they have to have **arcane** *cure* spells on scrolls - they can't share with the cleric, but they can with the witch.  Likewise a bard's *cure* scrolls can't be used by the cleric.  Wands are a different story.

Comment: @Bobson Pathfinder doesn't really make the distinction between arcane and divine scrolls. In fact, this is mandated in official PFS play: "For the sake of simplicity, there is no difference between an arcane and divine scroll or wand." Guide to PFS Organized Play, p. 24.

Comment: @PaulZ - Interesting.  The *system* explicitly does (as per the quote in the OP), but I hadn't realized that PFS did away with that.  Not that my characters use many scrolls.

Comment: @Bobson note that you still *can* share scrolls like that, but at least one of the casters will need to making UMD checks.

Comment: @thedarkwanderer - True, but once you bring in UMD, you can share spells with the party rogue (or fighter) the same way.